How to use sqlite database for testing ignoring the schema name needed in production
I am using Symfony Framework 6.4 and so far I had Doctrine's ORM 2.19 and DBAL 3.9 in use.
Now I tried upgrading to ORM 3.x and DBAL 4.x but encountered a problem I cannot solve, due to some BC breaks listed here for ORM and here for DBAL regarding the removal of sqlite schema emulation.
Situation:

Production DB (Oracle) is not under my control and has all tables in a schema/namespace, lets call it MY_STUFF.
Testing/Dev DB is sqlite which does not support schema namespaces.
Entities are attributed with #[ORM\Table(schema: 'MY_STUFF', name: 'ITEMS_VIEW')].
In config/packages/doctrine.yaml I have the sqlite connection configured for test and dev environments.
With DBAL4/ORM3 in test and dev inserting fixtures for example try to INSERT INTO MY_STUFF.ITEMS_VIEW which fails. With the old versions there was Schema Emulation that converted the Table name to MY_STUFF__ITEMS_VIEW and worked fine.

So now I need to work around missing schema support myself but cannot figure out how to do it. In the ORM 3 docs there is an example of how to modify table names via a listener but it is the same as in ORM 2 and does not work because of removed functionality (see BC breaks).
What I tried / ideas:

Made EventListeners for postGenerateSchema and loadClassMetadata events and was able to get table and schema names. Unfortunately I could not find a way to actually modify this information to drop the schema name or merge it into the table name.
Had the Idea to make my own subclass of ORM\Table attribute but is is marked as final.
Tried to set schema in #[ORM\Table(schema: 'MY_STUFF', name: 'ITEMS_VIEW')] only in specific environment but all values must be constant so no logic is allowed in the Attribute.
I could switch to staticphp as mentioned in the docs for DoctrineBundle to add logic but I must configure the whole Entity via PHP without being able to use Attributes, right?
It would be nice to add a "default schema name" on connection basis so I could change it for every environment but this doesn't seem to be possible.

No. 1 seems to be the most promising approach.
